# Sonicwall NSA 2400 Not switching back to Primary VPN after Failover

Tags: networking, vpn, firewall, sonicwall

We are experiencing an issue with our SonicWall NSA 2400 Firewall.  We have a secondary gateway over IPSec setup in the event of a failure of our main ISP (which is unfortunately common).  The secondary gateway is a 4G connection through Verizon and the cost grows as data usage increases.

The firewall switches over to the secondary gateway properly, but then *sometimes* will not renegotiate and switch back to the primary when it comes back up.  Hitting 'Renegotiate' on both sides seems to fix the issue, but I am wondering if there is something I am missing that may be causing it to stay on the secondary.

I don't think this has anything to do with the settings as it seems to work 50% of the time, but here they are anyway in case someone has some tips on how to ensure switching back to primary when the connection is restored.

Policy Type: Site to Site

Auth Method: IKE using Preshared Secret

IKE Phase 1 proposal:

Exchange: Main Mode

DH Group: Group 1

Encrypt: AES-256

Auth: SHA1

Lifetime: 3600 (seconds)

Phase 2 proposal:

Protocol: ESP

Encrypt: AES-256

Auth: SHA1

Lifetime: 900 (seconds)

Keep Alive is enabled, and Preempt Secondary Gateway is enabled at 120 second interval.

Comment: So they're just letting you know right in the product name that it's government backdoored these days huh?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three things to check:

1. The preempt to secondary gateway option MUST be active even on the remote peer
2. On the 4G-enabled firewall, edit your WWAN connection profile and set it to "persistent connection" or "dial on data"
3. In the load-balancing page, edit the LB Group and check that your WWAN connection is selected as the "final backup interface"

Answer (score 1):

You can have your VPN to fail back to the primary gateway by checking the "Preempt Secondary Gateway" box and specifying a desired interval for a failback attempt.

[image: See screenshot]